# Is it possible to save this proof of the symmetry of Hessian matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I was reading Shifrin's "Multivariable calculus", and stuck upon the proof of the symmetry of Hessian matrix. I am really not happy with it as it requires introduction of coordinates, so it seemed natural to me to try to introduce the Hessian in coordinate-free way as follows:

We say, that a function $f\colon V\to W$ between Euclidean spaces is twice differentiable at $v\in V$ if it is differentiable in a neighbourhood of $v$, and there exists a bilinear map $D_2f(v)\colon V\times V \to W$ and
for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $h,k\in V$ with $\|\:h\|\:,\|\:k\|\: < \delta$  we have
$$\frac{\|\:Df(v+h)k - Df(a)k - D_2f(v)(h,k)\|\:}{\|\:h\|\:\|\:k\|\:} < \epsilon.$$

So the question is to prove the symmetry of $D_2f(v)$. A natural way would be to estimate
$$A =  \frac{ \|\:D_2f(v)(h,k) - D_2f(v)(k,h)\|\:}{\|\:h\|\:\|\:k\|\:}.$$

So we fix $\epsilon > 0$. By hypothesis, we can find $\delta$ such that for any $h,k$ of norm less than $\delta$ we have
$$ A < 2 \epsilon  + \frac{ \|\:Df(v + h)k - Df(v)k - Df(v + k)h - Df(v)h\|\:}{\|\:h\|\:\|\:k\|\:} $$

And now we try to use the definition of the derivative:

For any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any $h\in V$ with $ \|\:h\|\:< \delta$ we have
$$\frac{\|\:f(v + h) - f(v) - Df(v)h\|\:}{\|\:h\|\:} < \epsilon.$$

Decreasing $\delta$ if needed we use triangle inequality four times and conclude
$$ A < 2\epsilon + 2\frac {\epsilon}{\|\:h\|\:} + 2\frac {\epsilon}{\|\:k\|\:}$$
(all the remaining terms vanish identically).

So the question is if it is possible to get rid of the norms of $h$ and $k$ in the denominators?

Comment: Where did the definition come from? The product in the denominator troubles me, since it is undefined when either $h$ or $k$ is $0$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I just think about it as an operator norm of an operator from $V\otimes V$ to $W$ (i.e. the maximum of the norm on the restriction to the unit sphere in $V\otimes V$)

Comment: This does not address my complaint. At any rate, for a coordinate-free proof of the symmetry of the second derivative, see Lang's *Real Analysis* or Dieudonné's *Elements of Analysis* (VIII, 12, in my French edition of it).

Comment: @TedShifrin Aha! Probably I have got your point. I have to require $h,k \ne 0$ (and there should be a similar requirement for the definition of the first derivative as well)

Thank you so much for the reference!